# Lucene and servlet integration

Tags: java, servlets, lucene

I may be building a Java servlet app that will need to integrate with a very simple Lucene index.  The index will be searchable on only a single field, and then I want to send the results back, probably as XML, maybe JSON, but that doesn't really matter at this point.  The main thing is that the index itself is not a problem.

My question is how the two should be integrated.  My inclination is to access the index programmatcally from the servlet app, and therefore I'd run it and store it in a ServletContextListener.  I could then build a fairly simple console to turn the search service on and off.  I could also have a single app that would take care of requests, as well as periodically rebuild the index, then swap the new one in to replace the old.  One potential issue that arises is how to get the servlet to behave and wait a bit if/when the index is being swapped out.  It should take less than a second, and I could do that at 2 AM, but I'd still like it to be as bullet-proof as possible.  If a servlet makes a request to a service and has to wait, what kind of timeout is involved?  Where/how do I control this?

Other possibilities are to run the index as a standalone Java app, or to run it in a separate servlet app, and let the first app make http calls to it through a servlet.  I don't see much benefit in the last approach, it just adds more code that doesn't really serve any purpose.  There would be no reason for the search requests to be directly accessible from HTTP.

What are your thoughts?  I appreciate any input from someone experienced along this line.

Comment: Why would you periodically rebuild the index? Why not just add documents to it on an as-needed basis?

Comment: I need a clean data set every week.  If a record isn't in the new feed, it should not be in the index.  Just a business requirement.

Comment: So you're basically trying to work around the time it takes to switch the app to do the lookup in a different index (switching a filename), once a week?

Comment: That's one thing.  My larger question is if it sounds right to put the IndexSearcher into a ServletContextListener as part of the same servlet app that also responds to requests, or if it should be separate.

Comment: I don't see any reason to make it a separate app, unless you want to just make it a [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) instance, which provides other benefits as well.

Comment: Right.  I think solr would be overkill in this case, providing benefits I don't need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind is that the recommendation is to have a single `IndexWriter`. We went the route of keeping it inside the servlet, and a problem we faced is that with an NLB pair you have two servlets, each of whom want to write. This requires you to either pay a hefty performance penalty, or else somehow designate one of them as the writer.

If you have more than two servers, this problem of course becomes even more acute. But if you're talking about everything running inside a single process, then maybe this isn't something to worry about.

I'd encourage you to reconsider Solr. It does in some sense have a bigger feature set, so I can understand why you would feel like it's "overkill", but it's usually quicker to set up and easier to use - meaning that pure Lucene might be the one that's overkill.